# Play Soap Client

Tags: scala, playframework

I am reading this article

https://playframework.github.io/play-soap/SbtWsdl.html

and based on this. I wrote the following build.sbt file

```
name := "PlaySOAPClient"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.typesafe.play" % "play-soap-client_2.11" % "1.1.3"
)

WsdlKeys.packageName := Some("com.foo")
WsdlKeys.wsdlTasks in Compile := Seq(
   WsdlKeys.WsdlTask((sourceDirectory.value / "main" / "wsdl" / "foo.wsdl").toURI.toURL)
)
```

and plugins.sbt

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("play-sbt-plugins", url("https://dl.bintray.com/playframework/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-soap" % "1.1.3")
```

When I do `sbt compile` the plugin does generate some code. but that code does not compile

```
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'PlaySoapClient.class'.
Could not access type Configuration in value play.api,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'PlaySoapClient.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of play.api.
Warning:scalac: Class javax.inject.Singleton not found - continuing with a stub.
/Users/User/IdeaProjects/PlaySOAPClient/target/scala-2.11/wsdl/main/sources/com/foo/webservices/FooWebService.scala
Error:(13, 8) object inject is not a member of package javax
@javax.inject.Singleton
Error:(14, 107) object api is not a member of package play
class FooWebService @javax.inject.Inject() (apacheCxfBus: play.soap.ApacheCxfBus, configuration: play.api.Configuration) extends play.soap.PlaySoapClient(apacheCxfBus, configuration) {
Error:(14, 32) object inject is not a member of package javax
class FooWebService @javax.inject.Inject() (apacheCxfBus: play.soap.ApacheCxfBus, configuration: play.api.Configuration) extends play.soap.PlaySoapClient(apacheCxfBus, configuration) {
```

Does anyone have an idea of what dependencies are missing. Note that this is a client side application only using this library to make a soap call. I don't want any server side dependencies of play framework.

My hope is that I will be able to use the play-soap as a standalone library in my console application to make soap calls.

Comment: What is your version of sbt? What's in `src/main/wsdl/foo.wsdl`?

Comment: sbt.version = 0.13.16. foo.wsdl explains the SOAP endpoint. the plugin is looking at this file to generate the soap proxy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dependency to *build.sbt*

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.6.7" intransitive()
```

Then `sbt compile` should work (after `sbt update`).

Comment: But that includes the entire play framework server side in my application. Upon reading the documentation of the play-soap I got the indication that it can be used independantly without depending on the entire play framework.

Comment: No, entire Play framework requires more dependencies in build.sbt and `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.7")` in plugins.sbt. Without this dependency you will have no `play.api.Configuration` (see your error message). What the trouble to add this dependency?

Comment: The problem is my library is used in many applications. there is too much conflict. I must keep dependencies to a minimum. That is why I want to keep my footprint of dependencies to the least amount possible.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct. This library cannot be used in a standalone mode. So we have to pull in the play framework.

Comment: This should really be stated in the docs, I was also very confused by this.

Comment: It also didn't work when I ran with `intransitive()` in the end, but only without.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, including the entire Play Framework into the application purely for the sake of WSDL client seems to be too much. All you need is to generate annotated Java beans and make a dependency just on them. And you can actually do that with common tools i.e. using Java's `wsimport` and `sbt` tasks to wrap it around.

Consider the following bootstrap template for this: https://github.com/sainnr/sbt-scala-wsdl-template. It generates all the boilerplate in-flight, compiles before the main `sbt` project and eliminates the need to commit this boilerplate Java code to your pristine Scala repo. If you notice, it doesn't even require a complete application server, just throw in some JavaEE-ish libs like `rt.jar` or its alternatives. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Btw, wrote a complete post on this topic https://fullstackme.co.uk/dev/automate-soap-client-auto-generation-routines-with-wsdl-import-for-sbt-and-scala